# Setting a collection parameter as a list for column values

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying to write a query with a Collection parameter. It is assumed that query would turn this collection to a column of its values for the further operations. I'm using Spring, so now my query looks like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id FROM unnest(array[?1]) id", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> getIds(Collection<String> ids);
```

It doesn't work, because Hibernate set collections as parameters in braces, so the real query will be send to DB:

```
SELECT id FROM unnest(array[('1', '2')]) id
```

This is not a valid query, the error is raising:

> ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning
>   "record" SQL state: 42601

Right version of it must be:

```
SELECT id FROM unnest(array['1', '2']) id
```

So please can anybody tell me, if there is a way I could set a collection as query parameter without braces? Or maybe there is an another way to turn collection to column?

Comment: I have something akin to a solution, but honestly this is an operation for which you shouldn't go through the database.

Comment: @coladict I have no idea how can I pass list of strings as a column to query, so any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: It's not a list. You need to pass an array. I have published a library for that, but this is completely pointless for the query in your question. You are just telling your database to *echo* something back to you.

Comment: @Jeff have you been able to solve this?

Comment: @coladict the OP asked how to do it, not whether it makes sense. This happens quite often with CTEs in more complicated queries .